# TypeScript - Why is a static property that is set to a defined object not known at compile time to be defined?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, static, undefined-reference

I'm trying to access a static property of a class. I get the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'` when I try to compile it. Why is a static property that is set to a defined object not known at compile time to be defined?

I have three classes each defined in their own file:

DirectoryContents.ts

```js
export class DirectoryContents
{
    public readonly directories: ReadonlyArray<string>;

    public readonly files: ReadonlyArray<string>;

    public constructor(directories: ReadonlyArray<string>, files: ReadonlyArray<string>)
    {
        this.directories = directories;
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

RootDirStructure.ts

```js
01| import {DirectoryContents} from "./DirectoryContents";
02| import ReadOnlyDict = NodeJS.ReadOnlyDict;
03|
04| export class RootDirStructure
05| {
06|     private static readonly REQUIRED_NPM_DIRECTORIES: ReadonlyArray<string> =
07|         ["node_modules"];
08|
09|     private static readonly REQUIRED_NPM_FILES: ReadonlyArray<string> =
10|         ["package.json", "package-lock.json"];
11|
12|     // RootDirStructure.required.npm set to defined object
13|     public static readonly required: ReadOnlyDict<DirectoryContents> =
14|         {
15|             npm: new DirectoryContents(RootDirStructure.REQUIRED_NPM_DIRECTORIES, RootDirStructure.REQUIRED_NPM_FILES)
16|         }
17| }
```

Index.ts

```js
01| import {RootDirStructure} from "./RootDirStructure";
02|
03| class Index
04| {
05|     // The following reference to RootDirStructure.required.npm causes error
06|     const requiredNPMDirectories: ReadonlyArray<string> = RootDirStructure.required.npm.directories;
07| }
```

On line 15 of `RootDirStructure.ts`, its static property gets set to a defined object. Yet when the object is referenced on line 6 of `Index.ts`, it creates the `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error.

Since it's a static property whose value should be known at compile time, why is a static property that is set to a defined object not known at compile time to be defined?

Comment: Just remove the explicit type definition: `public static readonly required = { npm: ... }`

Comment: You don't show the `ReadOnlyDict` definition but I guess it something like `{ [key: string]: T }`, so `npm` is not guaranteed to be defined - hence the error

Comment: @AlekseyL. When I do that my IDE gives me all sorts of errors :(

`ReadOnlyDict` is a built in type to NodeJS, but I'm fairly certain your surmise that it's `{ [key: string]: T }` is correct. I believe it's essentially a plain old JS object with string keys and the type value specified via the provided type parameter argument. In this case `DirectoryContents `. And the resulting object is then frozen. But shouldn't the compiler be able to infer that `npm` is defined since it's defined statically? It can check the value of it at compile time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by rewriting `RootDirStructure.ts`.

I made the static property `RootDirStructure.required` a static inner class instead of a property with type `ReadOnlyDict<DirectoryContents>` so now `RootDirStructure.ts` looks like:

```js
import {DirectoryContents} from "./DirectoryContents";

export class RootDirStructure
{
    private static readonly REQUIRED_NPM_DIRECTORIES: ReadonlyArray<string> =
        ["node_modules"];
    private static readonly REQUIRED_NPM_FILES: ReadonlyArray<string> =
        ["package.json", "package-lock.json"];
    // RootDirStructure.required.npm set to defined object
    public static readonly required = class
    {
        public static readonly npm: DirectoryContents = new DirectoryContents(RootDirStructure.REQUIRED_NPM_DIRECTORIES, RootDirStructure.REQUIRED_NPM_FILES);
    }
}
```

I'm still interested and wonder why I was getting the error before. I prefer the original syntax.